# Automatically show qTip (jQuery plugin) tooltip after page load

Tags: jquery, qtip

Has anyone ever used qTip to create a tooltip that responds to a click on an element, but also is set to popup after the page loads?  I tried playing around with setTimeout, but I can't seem to get it to load automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

You can define qtip to display in any event you like, simply by configuring it to not display in an event, but at your whim. For instance:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div.some-element').qtip({
        content: 'This is the tooltip',
        show: {
            when: false, // Don't specify a show event
            ready: true // Show the tooltip when ready
        },
        hide: false // Don't specify a hide event
    })
});
```