# Full calender with description

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a code for Fullcalender. I used [Adam shaw's Full calender plugin](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). In that i just wanted to add some description for each events. But when i use [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/). It give me description but its only on Hover.

My code is

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
       var y = date.getFullYear();
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'month, basicWeek, basicDay',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'today,prev, next',
            },
            //events: "Calendar.asmx/EventList",
            //defaultView: 'dayView',
            events: [
            {
                title: 'DIWALI',
                start: new Date(2012,09,2),
                description: 'Today\'s Diwali',
                id: 1
            },
            {
                title: 'Long Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, d - 5),
                end: new Date(y, m, 1),
                description: 'long description3',
                id: 2
            }],
            eventRender: function(event, element) {
                element.qtip({
                    content: event.description + '<br />' + event.start,
                    style: {
                        background: 'black',
                        color: '#FFFFFF'
                    },
                    position: {
                        corner: {
                            target: 'center',
                            tooltip: 'bottomMiddle'
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        });
```

I just want to have description on display page. Can anyone help on this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060955/automatically-show-qtip-jquery-plugin-tooltip-after-page-load

Comment: Question is not clear..Do you want to show the description on the calender with blue background or  when the users clicks on that event you want to show them description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060955/automatically-show-qtip-jquery-plugin-tooltip-after-page-load) will help you to get the solution for your question.

Refer the answers below this.